# HTC Vive Grabbing Object Trigger

Tags: 3d, game-design, virtual-reality, htc-vive, steam-vr

I'm doing a HTC Vive VR game with Unity.

I have 3 objects, and I want to trigger different events when the player pick up different objects.

Since I set the rigidbody to the controller and don't want these events to be triggered by moving the objects by accident, I need to set up two rules: 1) the object is out of the invisible bounding box it is in; 2) object is being hold by he player with the trigger.

How should I script that?